# Jenkins: export pipeline into groovy-dsl file

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins job configured through web interface.

The configuration is relatively simple, all it does is loading the project from git and running the build depending on  brunch name based on `Jenkinsfile`.

Despite of its simpleness I would like to store the configuration in git.

**Q 1:** How can I export a job into a groovy dsl?

**Q 2:** In case if it is not possible, how can I create a groovy dsl for my job?

The job currently has only "Branch Sources:Git" section which contains field like repository, credentials and branches; Build Configuration (by Jenkinsfile) and Orphaned section.

**Update:**

I wrote the corresponding dsl manually:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('MyPipeline') {

    branchSources {
        git {
            remote("git@my.domain:project/subproject.git")
            credentialsId("mycredentionals")
            includes('master feature* bugfix*')
        }
    }

    orphanedItemStrategy {
        discardOldItems {
            numToKeep(0)
            daysToKeep(0)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You do know that if you only want to _store_ the configuration to git, but will only be modifying it from the web interface, you can export it to xml from /jenkins/job/JobName/config.xml, and store that?

Comment: @TeemuRisikko thank you. I'd already wrote the dsl manually. See my update.